# Write multiple kernels or a Single kernel

Tags: opencl

Suppose that I've two big functions. Is it better to write them in a separate kernels and call them sequentially, or is better to write only one kernel? (I don't want to read the data back and force form between host and device in between). What about the speed up if I want to call the kernel many times?

Comment: have a look here, similar discussion: stackoverflow.com/questions/9208535/how-to-handle-a-variable-number-of-algorithms-in-a-kernel

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One thing to consider is the effect of register pressure on hardware utilization and performance.

As a general rule, big kernels have big register footprints. Typical OpenCL devices (ie. GPUs) have very finite register file sizes and large kernels can result in lower concurrency (fewer concurrent warps/wavefronts), less opportunities for latency hiding, and poorer overall performance. On the other hand, kernel launch overheads are pretty low on most platforms, so if your algorithm doesn't have an enormous amount of state to save between "phases" of execution, the penalty of using multiple kernels can be rather low.

Using multiple kernels also has another side benefit -- you get implicit synchronization between all work units for free. Often that can eliminate the need for atomic memory operations and synchronization primitives which can have a negative impact on code performance.

The ultimate guide should be measured performance. There is no universal rule-of-thumb for this sort of things. Benchmarking is the only way to know for sure.

Comment: Apple agree: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/OpenCL_MacProgGuide/TuningPerformanceOntheGPU/TuningPerformanceOntheGPU.html

Answer (score 3):

In general this is a question of (maybe) slightly better performance vs. readibility of your code. Copying buffers is no issue as long as you keep them within the same context. E.g. you could set one output buffer of a kernel to be an input buffer of the next kernel, which would not involve any copying.

Answer (score 3):

The proper way to code in OpenCL is to separate your code into parallel tasks, and each of them is a kernel. This is, each "for loop" should be a kernel. Some times one single CPU code function could result in a 4 kernel implementation in OCL.

If you need to store data between kernel executions just use OpenCL buffers and do not copy to host (this solves the DEVICE<->HOST bottleneck).

If both functions act to different data you could propably write a single kernel, but that depends on the complexity of the operation being run.